# Just started a Vanguard Roth IRA at 19 years old starting with $3k in the account. What is the next step in gworing that money?

Tags: stocks, roth-ira

How do you become a millionaire by 60 if you start a Roth IRA early? I have heard it said that investing index funds and the like over time, can grow money with compound interests over time, but I'm a bit confused on the next step.

Answer (score 2):

Not a lot of information to go on, but if you contribute $900 a month at 4% for 40 years you'll end up with slightly more than $1,000,000... If you wait another 10 years you'd need to save $1500 a month for the same outcome.

Comment: Should be noted that OP can't put all $900/month into the Roth IRA as those are limited to $6000 or total earned income on the year. Other vehicles do exist, however where that savings can be made.

Comment: You're right... He'll need a higher interest rate to make his $1M with a Roth...

Answer (score 1):

Yes but you have to do a bit more. In my opinion you are smart for asking the question. I wish that I did when I was your age (sometime during the Jurassic era). [Here](https://www.fool.com/retirement/2019/05/19/heres-what-it-takes-to-retire-a-millionaire-no-mat.aspx) is something to give food for thought but keep asking the question and see what advice you get.